# TextField Keyboard startup in Number mode

Tags: ios, numbers, uitextfield

I need the UITextField "ASCII Capable" keyboard to come up in numeric mode.  I can't find an API for this, what am I missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you have a `UITextField` named `textField`, all you need to do is call the method:

```
[ textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation ];
```

You may need to call this *before* the keyboard is displayed.

Comment: I do not want the "Numeric & Punctuation" keyboard, I need the "ASCII Capable" keyboard in numeric mode--as if the bottom left numeric key had been pressed.

Comment: With iPhone programming, it's better to pick the best of the available options than it is to chase after wild geese.

Comment: UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation is the "ASCII Capable" keyboard in numeric mode, I missed this simple fact.

Answer (score 0):

from the documentation does this help?

> The appearance of the keyboard itself can be customized using the
>   properties provided by the
>   **UITextInputTraits** protocol. Text field
>   objects implement this protocol and
>   support the properties it defines. You
>   can use these properties to specify
>   the type of keyboard (ASCII, Numbers,
>   URL, Email, and others) to display.
>   You can also configure the basic text
>   entry behavior of the keyboard, such
>   as whether it supports automatic
>   capitalization and correction of the
>   text.

Comment: Not really, I have looked at the UITextInputTraits.  I have seen other apps that do this but don't know if it is via a private API.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using Interface Builder?  If so, click on the text field, then go to the Text Field Attributes.  There will be an attribute for Keyboard.  Change it to Number Pad.

Comment: I don't want the "Number Pad", I need the "ASCII Capable" keyboard in numeric mode--as if the bottom left numeric key had been pressed.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to get to it?  When I try to dial and click on the button left numeric key, I get prompted to add a contact.

Comment: Open Notes App, click in a note to enter a value.  Click on the lower left keyboard button which is labeled ".?123".  That is what I need but I want the keyboard to come selected like that.